# What's the simplest way of horizontally aligning a Font Awesome icon in the center of a div using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, web-frontend

I want to create 3 icons that are sitting at the bottom of my webpage:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>contact</h1>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></div> 
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And your question/problem/issue is...?

Comment: I wanted to make sure the easiest way possible that each icon is sitting in the horizontal middle of the div it's nested in.

Comment: you mean the closest ancestor div? life would be easier if we stopped using divs everywhere…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-center`  class to your div.

Comment: Yeah, it did the job.